# How to call correctly few class (intents) using a button?

Tags: android, class, button, android-intent, oncreate

I'm beginner in Java Android developing. I'm using Eclipse SDK 3.6.1 version. I'm trying to do call new intents, but my app is always unexpectedly stopped. Do am I correctly call new intents?

> First class:

```
public class first extends Activity {


  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignIn);
    SignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          EditText pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPasswd);
            if(pw.getText().toString().equals("123")) {                     

                 Intent intent = new Intent(first.this, second.class);
                 startActivity(intent);                                  
             }
            else {
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong PIN" ,
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }   

      }});
  }
 }
```

> Second class:

```
public class second extends Activity {

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginas);   

    Button Button01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    Button01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

    public void onClick(View v) {
      if(v.getId() == R.id.Button01) { 

          Intent intent = new Intent(second.this, third.class);
          startActivity(intent); 
     }} 
    });
  }
}
```

> Third class:

```
public class third extends Activity {

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lock);
  }}
```

When I put correct pin code the app show messages "the application () has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again". First I want to know that my code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

whatever the activity u want to display must and mension those activities in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.For example in ur application first,second,third activities mention in `AndroidManifest.xml` file